# Removing quotes outside of a field leaving appostaphe as is

Tags: shell, hiveql

I have a sample file which needs to be loaded in Hive Table

sample file : 'data','kumar's','big'data','Hive','impala-shell'

I need output in this way : data,kumar's,big'data,Hive,impala-shell

I need only outside quotes to be removed.

Suggest me if you any Hive table definition or shell command to remove only outside quotes

Answer (score 0):

```
$ echo "'data','kumar's','big'data','Hive','impala-shell'"
'data','kumar's','big'data','Hive','impala-shell'

$ echo "'data','kumar's','big'data','Hive','impala-shell'" |
> sed -E "s/^'|'$//g; s/','/,/g"
data,kumar's,big'data,Hive,impala-shell
```

Remove single-quotes at start and end of line, and any that surround a comma.